# Layout Renderer with Dependency Injection Not Working

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, nlog

I have followed the https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/How-to-write-a-custom-layout-renderer article to create a layout renderer. The hello-world example works find, but when I go it inject something it is not writting anything.

1. I've removed the constructor injection and the logging is working as expected.
2. I've injected the same item into a constructor of a controller and that works.

```
// NOTE: ICorrelationContextAccessor is part of the CorrelationId nuget package
[LayoutRenderer("correlation-id")]
public class CorrelationIdLayoutRenderer : LayoutRenderer
{
    private readonly ICorrelationContextAccessor _correlationContext;

    public CorrelationIdLayoutRenderer(ICorrelationContextAccessor correlationContext)
    {
        _correlationContext = correlationContext;
    }

    protected override void Append(StringBuilder builder, LogEventInfo logEvent)
    {
        var correlation = _correlationContext.CorrelationContext.CorrelationId;

        builder.Append(correlation);
    }
}
```

nlog.config

```
<extensions>
    <add assembly="NLog.Web.AspNetCore"/>
    <add assembly="[[ My assembly is here]]"/>
</extensions>
<targets>
 <target xsi:type="File" name="ownFile-web" fileName="[[PATH]]/nlog-own-${shortdate}.log"
                layout="${longdate}|${level:fixedLength=True:padding=5:padCharacter= :upperCase=True}|${correlation-id}|${message} ${exception:format=tostring}" />
</targets>
```

I expect that the correlation should be coming through.

Comment: See also wiki: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Dependency-injection-with-NLog

Answer (score 1):

You need to override the `CreateInstance` in NLog, so it could create the `CorrelationIdLayoutRenderer`

```cs
ConfigurationItemFactory.Default.CreateInstance = (Type type) =>
{ 
    // your custom target.
    if(type == typeof(CorrelationIdLayoutRenderer))
      return new CorrelationIdLayoutRenderer(...); // TODO get ICorrelationContextAccessor 
    else
      return Activator.CreateInstance(type); //default
};
```

Update:

If you registering is too late, you could queue a reload of all assemblies by NLog as follows:

```
ConfigurationItemFactory.Default = null; // (namespace NLog.Config).
```

It will be reloaded just before first usage of NLog

Comment: Julian, I sort of understand this but what about when you need to inject the serviceprovider in as the parameter.

This would mean that the configuration you mention is needed to be done at the end of the ConfigureServices method of the Startup.cs. However when I try for this it is still not working.

Comment: If you registering is too late, you could queue a reload of all assemblies by NLog as follows: `ConfigurationItemFactory.Default = null` (namespace NLog.Config). It will be reloaded just before first usage of NLog.

Comment: @Stephen Cossgrove
Im facing the same issue. The problem is that I want to use IServiceProvider in my layout renderers, but its not created until ConfigureServices has run. I could set ConfigurationItemFactory.Default.CreateInstance at the end of ConfigureServices method, but manually calling IServiceCollection.BuildServiceProvider  would result in duplicated singleton services. Did you manage to solve this?